# Android Studio Render Issue

Tags: android

Alright, I have spent 3~ hours total trying to fix this issue, and I can't for the life of me figure it out. I'm trying to start programming in Android Studio and I'm following TheNewBostons tutorials. I've followed it exactly, and every time that I switch the theme to "Material.Light" I get a Rendering Issue.

Here's the issue:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XWRM.png)

I've tried several different fixes, like switching the renderer to a lower version of Android, editing styles.xml or something like that, and nothing has fixed it.

I've just started a new project, and haven't done a single thing. Does anyone have any light they can shed on this?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Support Design Library, and when you use the design library you must use a theme that extends `Theme.AppCompat`, as the error message says:

`You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or decendant) with the design library.`

So instead of selecting `Material.Light`, rather select `Appcompat.Light`.